# what are the steps to get this answer?

Tags: polynomials

If $\frac ab+\frac ba=1$, and if "a" and "b" are not equal to zero then what would be the value of $a^3-b^3$? It would be helpful if the answer is given in the form of steps leading to the value.

Comment: There are no real $a,b$ satisfying this equation.

Comment: @user426, won't it be $a^3+b^3$?

Comment: It is $a^3 - b^3$

Comment: Is there any identity for $a^3 - b^3$?

Comment: @user426, yes $(a-b)^3+3ab(a-b)=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$

Comment: @user426, I meant $$a^3-b^3=(a-b)^3+3ab(a-b)=(a-b)(a^2+b^2+ab)$$

Comment: Then from first expression we get $a^2+b^2 = ab$. Will this help in any way to get the answer?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8959/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-user426)

Comment: @vadim123 I don't think so. The optional answer are 1, -1, 0 or 1/2.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I tried going in chat room but it is not loading.

Comment: If  "The optional answer are 1, -1, 0 or 1/2" either $a/b+b/a=-1$ or it's $a^3+b^3$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee In case of that change in sign it does gives the answers from the options. Could be some typo error.

Comment: If $\frac ab+\frac ba=-1\implies  a^2+b^2+ab=0$ and $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I was typing up my answer and saw all your comments. I agree with you. Let me know if you want to post an answer, and I'd pull mine down.

Comment: @CalvinLin, no no. It's OK. Just joking. Concurrency issue is obvious here.

Comment: I think only answers can be accepted. For the time being, you can safely focus on the basic algebraic formulae.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thanks for help.

Comment: @user426,my pleasure. But why did you un-accept the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Lab's comments,

Making the assumption that $\frac{a}{b} + \frac{a}{b} = -1 $,

**Hint:** Clear denominators for the equation. It states that

$$a^2 + b^2 = -ab$$

**Hint:** $$a^3 -b^3 = (a-b)(a^2 + b^2 + ab) = ??$$

---

If we want $a^3 + b^3$ instead, we can proceed in a similar manner.

Comment: Nice coincidence : your answer and my comment